# Execute a .exe file automatically after installation

Tags: .net, windows-installer, custom-action

I have a .exe file, which should be executed as soon as the installation of the main application is finished.

I understand this can be achieved using Custom action. I need a little assistance in creating a Custom action. I'm using VS2008, .NET 3.5,

As I'm new to c#, if the suggetions are in detail, would help me understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d.aspx), even though it is in VB.NET it applies to C# as well.

The most important part is (translated to C#) creating a new Class Library, and adding a new Installer Class with the following content:

```
override void Commit(IDictionary savedState)
{
    base.Commit(savedState);
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("myApp.exe");
}
```

As stated in the article you can then create a new custom action with a reference to your just created project.